# IIS logs 200 status but returns 500 status

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to diagnose an issue where IIS7.5 shows a successful (200) response in the IIS logs, but a "Service temporarily unavailable" HTML message is returned to the browser with a 500 status, after 30 seconds.

Some more details:

- I'm calling a WebAPI endpoint to run an import function that involves files and database entries.
- The import takes anywhere from 40 - 70 seconds to complete.
- The IIS 7.5 logs show the request completing successfully:

  2013-12-09 10:45:17 10.177.197.244 POST /api/streamdata/ImportStream - 80 [...] Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/31.0.1650.63+Safari/537.36 200 0 64 1150 67120
- The import code also logs the import steps and shows the import is completed successfully.
- The browser receives an HTML page back, with the "Service Temporarily Unavailable" header and a 500 response code after 30 seconds.
- Using .NET4.5

What I've tried:

- Using Chrome and Firefox - same result either way.
- Adding a timeout to the jQuery AJAX request.  If this is set short (30 seconds) I get an actual timeout reported.  If this is set long (5 minutes) I get the service unavailable message as before.
- Using Fiddler client-side, and can see the server is responding with the 500 code (rather than it being something generated client-side).
- Checked out various IIS site and application-pool settings, but can't find one that explains this behaviour.
- Adjusted the import code to miss out some steps and take less than 30 seconds to complete.  In this case a normal 200 response was received by the browser.

So in summary, the code is running ok, but a service temporarily unavailable message is returned to the browser at 30 seconds into the request, even though the server is still happily processing the request to completion.

Any ideas on what is happening at 30 seconds and how to fix it gratefully received.

Comment: Do you have a proxy with a 30-second timeout between your client and the web server?

Comment: @Guntram Sounds plausible, thanks, but I don't know where I should look to find out.  IIS is running on a Windows 2008 R2 server hosted by Rackspace and the person who set it up has left...  Any suggestions where I should look?

Comment: Look at the IP address in the log - 10.177.197.244. This is a private IP address, so i'd assume the IP you see from "outside" is the IP of a proxy, which re-routes the request to the real server internally. Only rackspace support can help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the steer from Guntram I found the issue was a 30 second timeout in the load-balancer, which was where the HMTL error page was originating.

Once Rackspace increased the timeout period, everything worked normally again.